# looping a DateLastModified function through a column in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with data but I need to add the time at which the Data was created. This time is the "Last Modified"-time of the file I got the data from.

I already got all the filenames as in "filename.txt" in the first column of the worksheet so each line of data can be referenced to its file. I have this function to pull the LastModified-Date from the filename:

```
Function FileLastModified(strFullFileName As String)
strFullFileName = "C:\...\filefolder\" + Range("A1").Value
    Dim fs As Object, f As Object, s As String

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(strFullFileName)

    s = UCase(strFullFileName) & vbCrLf
    s = f.DateLastModified
    FileLastModified = s

    Set fs = Nothing: Set f = Nothing


End Function
```

Now I want the function to go through all the filenames in column A and put all the LastModified-Times in column D. So how do I edit this

```
strFullFileName = "C:\.....\" + Range("A1").Value
```

to automatically pull the filename from the A-Column?

Comment: What's this for? `s = UCase(strFullFileName) & vbCrLf` You're erasing that value of `s` immediately after assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim filenames As Variant
Dim lastModifiedTimes As Variant

'How many filenames are there? (should tailor this to your exact situation)
n = Range("A:A").Find("*", Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

filenames = Range("A1").Resize(n, 1).Value 'load all fnames from sheet to array

ReDim lastModifiedTimes(1 To n, 1 To 1)
For i = 1 To n
    lastModifiedTimes(i,1) = _
        FSO.GetFile("C:\.....\" & filenames(i,1)).DateLastModified
Next i

'Slap times array onto sheet
Range("D1").Resize(n, 1).Value = lastModifiedTimes
```

Note that I got rid of your `FileLastModified` wrapper function since it's really only wrapping one thing, and it can be replaced by one single line of code.